# wordpress even odd loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to achieve a loop that has an odd / even pattern within Wordpress. That doesn't work. It loops each post 10 times. How do I integrate the counting loop within the original foreach loop?

```
<?php  
$i=0;
$posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>9,'offset'=> 6));
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  if ($i % 2 == 0)
  { ?>
```

MY ODD CONTENT

```
<?php  }
    else
    {
 ?>
```

MY EVEN CONTENT

```
<?php  }
    }
?>



<?php
$i++;
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to split our loop in two for two post columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        //echo even
        echo "Even: " . $i . "<br/>";
    } else {
        //echo odd
        echo "Odd: " . $i . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

simple for loop

for your content:

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
   if($i % 2 == 0){
            //echo even
            echo "Even: " . $i . "<br/>";
        } else {
            //echo odd
            echo "Odd: " . $i . "<br/>";
        }
$i++
endforeach;
```

Complete code:

```
<?php  
$i=0;
$posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>9,'offset'=> 6));
foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
  if($i % 2 == 0){
        //echo even
        echo "Even: " . $i . "<br/>";
    } else {
        //echo odd
        echo "Odd: " . $i . "<br/>";
    }
$i++;
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ultra fast reply. Where do I have to integrate that?

Comment: remove that loop and and add my odd and even logic and you are good to go

Comment: @ScubaBen select my comment as answer if it resolves your problem.